# Nativescript - simulate a button press on a Label element

Tags: nativescript

I'm using a Label element as a button. The button element has too much padding that I can't seem to override.

On the Label, I'd like to give a "button" press feedback and I did the following during the ontap event callback

`

```
   let oldColor = item.backgroundColor;

   let newColor = new colorModule.Color( "red" );

   label.backgroundColor = newColor;

   setTimeout( () =>
   {
       label.backgroundColor = oldColor;
   }, 125 );
```

`

But the delay seems to be much longer than 125 msec - more like close to a second.

Any suggestions as to how I could do better.

Answer (score 1):

For your original issue (buttons have too much padding), it sounds like you are trying to apply styling to the button in CSS.

Instead, add XML properties to the button for the width and height that you want:

```
<Button text="TAP" tap="{{ onTap }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-active" width="150" height="25"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make a directive to imitate focus / hightlight effect on any object.
Create a directive file and add it to app.module

It change on event 'touch down' and 'touch up', property of element you choosed

directive.ts

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GestureTypes, TouchAction } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/gestures';

@Directive({selector: '[focus]'})
export class FocusDirective implements OnInit {
    private defaultColor: string;
    private color = '#000000';

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        const nativeElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
        this.defaultColor = nativeElement.color;
        // you can change here a lot of properties not only color

        nativeElement.on(GestureTypes.touch, ({action}) => {
            switch (action) {
                case TouchAction.down: {
                    nativeElement.color = this.color;
                    break;
                }
                case TouchAction.up: {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        nativeElement.color = this.defaultColor;
                    }, 80);
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    nativeElement.color = this.defaultColor;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Input() set focus(color: string) {
        if (color) {
            this.color = color;
        }
    }
}
```

template.html

```
<Label text="some text" focus="#FFF000"></Label>
```